# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode - Python 3

Tags: json, django, python-3.x, utf-8

I'm writing a Django site which grabs JSON data from several URLs (I'm using Python 3).

I'm getting the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x85 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

I've looked around, and it seems to be because of one or more illegal characters.

I tried encoding to something else and then decoding, but I'm very new to all of this, and I just cant get it to work.

```
r = urlopen("http://api.electromine.fr/stats")
        data = json.loads(r.read())
        print(data)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library instead

```
pip install requests
```

then

```
import requests
res = requests.get('https://api.electromine.fr/stats')
print res.json()
```